# Imported project to online Subversion server - but Tortoise SVN does not have commit as right click option

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I imported a project to an online Subversion server.  I changed a file and I want to commit - but Tortoise SVN only has the options: Repo-Browser, Settings, Help and About.  What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commit action is only available in working copies. From the TortoiseSVN documentation on [Importing Data Into A Repository](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-import.html):

> The folder imported does not become a working copy. You have to do a checkout to copy the files back from the server.